# Finding proper matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to find a "mechanic" way in order to solve such questions.

Find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ corresponding to the following:

$ A\cdot A=$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &2 \\ 0 &1 &0 \\ 0& 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}

Obviously its \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &1 \\ 0 &1 &0 \\ 0& 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}.

But it was more or less a guess. Is there a way or rule or something involving $A^{-1}$ or gaussian elimination or something else which allows to solve for more complex matrices given such question?

Comment: Do you know the jordan canonical form?

Comment: if you can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, i.e., spectral decomposition of $A^2,$  then you can find an $A$ to fit the given $A^2.$

Comment: If the eigenvalues of a real matrix  B are real then the jordan canonical form is very useful to find A such that p(A)=B, where p(x) is a  polynomial. See the following answer for an example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/990392/prove-the-following-equation-is-solvable-in-m-m-mathbb-c/990887#990887

Comment: Unfortunately, Im not familiar with these concepts. However, thank you for your suggestions!!